Transit Issues in Dubai and Paris with Separate Tickets and Expired Green Card (I-797 Extension)
Context:
I reside in Atlanta and recently traveled to Pakistan for my brother-in-law's wedding. On the way back to Atlanta, I made a stop in Riyadh to visit family. I am currently in Riyadh with my wife and our 1-year-old child. Both my child and I are U.S. citizens. My wife holds a Pakistani passport and a U.S. green card, which is expired, but she has an I-797 extension for 4 years.
Our itinerary:

Flynas from Riyadh to Dubai with a 3-hour layover.
Air France from Dubai to Atlanta via Paris.
Both airlines operate out of Terminal 1 in Dubai.


Dubai Transit Visa and Boarding in Riyadh:

We are traveling on separately purchased tickets and do not have visas for Dubai. Will this cause any issues when boarding our Flynas flight in Riyadh, considering we are not planning to leave the airport in Dubai? We have booked Marhaba Meet and Greet services, including baggage transfer, to help with the self-transfer process.


Check-in for Air France in Dubai:

How will I obtain boarding passes and check in for our Air France flight in Dubai? I have booked baggage transfer services, but I want to confirm that we won’t need to leave the terminal, especially considering our lack of Dubai visas.
Would it be advisable to only bring carry-on luggage to avoid any complications with checked baggage and the need to exit the terminal? Regardless, the check-in will still be a concern.


Transit Through Paris:

During our layover in Paris, will we encounter any issues due to my wife’s expired green card with the I-797 extension? We plan to remain in the non-Schengen area, but I’d appreciate confirmation or any additional insights.




Was the green card issued with a 10-year period of validity?

Related questions Do I always need to go through Immigration if I have a self-transfer and Do I need a visa to transit or layover in the Schengen area

What's "an I-797 extension for 4 years"? Is she waiting for GC renewal for 4 years now? Was her GC conditional (2-year validity)?

That’s correct her GC was 2 years, she came here on a finance visa and is now eligible for passport. The extension is just stating that.

In the comments you stated that your wife had a conditional 2-year green card that has expired, and is holding an "I-797 extension", which I assume is a receipt for filing a removal of conditions request (I-751). The receipt should include language stating that the conditional GC validity is extended for 48 months (see here).
The original green card together with the original I-797 that includes the statement of extension are considered to be a valid form I-551, which is what she needs to be able to board a flight to the US and enter back.

Dubai Transit Visa and Boarding in Riyadh

It appears that Pakistani citizens would need a transit visa for Dubai. Transit only (without entering the Schengen area) in France doesn't require visa for those with US residency. To exit the transit area, visa is required.

Check-in for Air France in Dubai:
How will I obtain boarding passes and check in for our Air France flight in Dubai? I have booked baggage transfer services, but I want to confirm that we won’t need to leave the terminal, especially considering our lack of Dubai visas.

You'll need to check with the airline(s). If the flights are on separate tickets you will probably need to collect your luggage, go outside, and check-in again to Air France. If they're on the same ticket, then it is possible that you'll get your luggage tagged all the way through at the first airport.

During our layover in Paris, will we encounter any issues due to my wife’s expired green card with the I-797 extension?

Who knows... It is possible that the airline staff might not know how to handle the extension, but not something that cannot be sorted out.

In the middle east airport hubs (DOH, DXB...) nobody needs a visa to transit without leaving the transit area.
